# Why is latency much greater if my process is idle between events?

Tags: c++, linux, performance, optimization, latency

I have a process that is blocked on a socket. When input becomes available in the socket the process decodes the input and most of the time does nothing but update an in memory structure. Periodically the input is such that more complex analysis is triggered, ultimately resulting in a outgoing message on another connection. I would like to minimize the latency in this later case, i.e. minimize the time between receiving and sending. What I have noticed is that latency numbers are 2x  worse when the time between interesting events increases. What could this be attributed to and how could I improve on it? I have tried to reserve a CPU for my process but I haven't see much of an improvement.

Comment: Can you show some codes for better illustration of the situation?

Comment: After more testing I think it was simply the instruction cache getting cold.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to "nice" the process to a negative value. I don't know the Linux scheduler in detail, but normal policy is to reduce the time slice (sometimes a quantum) when a process fails to use its slice up and vice versa.  This is called multi-level feedback policy.  In your case getting a bunch of quickly handled events probably gives the process a very short time slice. When a "significant" event occurs, it would have to work its way up to a longer slice through several context swaps. Setting the "nice" value high enough is likely to give it whatever time slice it needs.

Unfortunately "negative niceness" requires superuser privilege in most systems.